# Applying formatting to a Doughnut chart done with python pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am working on an automated ppt through a python-pptx. I am interested in applying character formatting to the data label through the next function but it does not work. I need help with figuring out why.

```
def apply_data_labels(self, chart):
        plot = chart.plots[0]
        plot.has_data_labels = True
        for series in plot.series:
            values = series.values
            counter = 0
            for point in series.points:
                data_label = point.data_label
                data_label.has_text_frame = True
                data_label.text_frame.text = str(values[counter])
                data_label.font.size = Pt(22)
                data_label.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255,160,122)
                counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data_label.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(22)
```

Things work a little differently when you're setting the font of an individual data label rather than all of them at once.